# JWT token authentication validation fails on Docker when HOST has time zone

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

> I have a dotnet 2.1 running with Dockerfile build targeted for Linux, core api with JWT token authorization, it works fine on in aws on azure, is all great, except for when I run it independently on my local with docker.

I try to create a shell and PowerShell launcher for all developers, UI, Mobile, and I'm facing a time zone issue.
On any local (windows, mac, linux - I didn't tried) time zone is UTC + 2, token is set the expire is 2 hours, when running the image with docker run token is valid for a couple of seconds, difference between when it was created and when it is expired on docker HOST Time zone.

If I run from visual studio in debug mode the docker file, docker container time is my host time, if I run it independently with docker run time on container is UTC.

There are solutions to force a time zone for docker the solution is to add an argument `--env TZ={timezone}` to docker run command. I will consider this as last option, because I would like to share the solution with team that is located on different time zones and different OS.

> So, is this a dotnet core issue? Does someone saw this problem before?

> Docker container is on GMT time zone, Host is on GMT + 2, token has expire DateTime.UtcNow + 2 hours, when validated on Docker container time zone fails, same docker container where it was issued. If I change Host time zone to < GMT + 2 it works, when validated on container.

Here is my token generation

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bigsecret"));

var token = new JwtSecurityToken
(
    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512)
)
{
    Payload =
    {
        ["claim1"] = "claim value 1",
    }
};

var token =  tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

And the Authentication builder

```
var validator = TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bigsecret")),
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
};

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
 // here is a negotiate scheme, not relevant for the example
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = validator;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = OnJwtMessageReceived, // no logic on task
        OnAuthenticationFailed = OnJwtAuthenticationFailed, // no logic on task
        OnTokenValidated = OnJwtTokenValidated // no logic on task
    };
});
```

I'm so frustrated because I don't believe this is a netcore bug, still I cannot get a hold of how is this happening because when I debug it from visual studio, time on the host is considered when issuing the token...
I don't know how to attach to a running container form visual studio so I can debug it there.

Comment: You wouldn't be running this on Docker Desktop on Windows would you? I've experienced silly issues like this one the host and container time zones drifted apart. I would create a token that was already expired when looking at it on the host. I could fix this by rebooting the PC - which was probably just restarting Hyper-V. Once I upgraded to WSL2 and started using WSL2 containers the problem disappeared.

Comment: Interesting, for me happens on mac the same, I think my windows docker has WSL2 but will double check, thank you.

Comment: @GlennSills docker is WSL2, restarted everything, windows service, nothing happens.

Comment: Could you capture the token, decode it a jwt.ms and post the JSON with the time at which the token was refused?

Comment: expire is UTC exact time +2 hours

Comment: Token is valid on the docker time, but still it fails on dotnet authorization when on docker. That is my problem. If I run it in debug from visual studio it works.

Comment: I forced a time zone (doesn't matter what time zone) on docker, it is what it is but it works, 

> docker run -e TZ=Europe/London -it --rm --name my-api -p 8080:80 my-api-image

Comment: This still sounds like a difference between your docker time and the host. Could you log the time of the container in UTC and compare it to the time on the host in UTC. I suspect they are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think your post had the answer in it. You said

> Docker container is on GMT time zone, Host is on GMT + 2, token has
> expire DateTime.UtcNow + 2 hours, when validated is validate on Docker
> Host time zone not on and it fails. If I change Host time zone to <
> GMT + 2 it works.

So, if you set a token to expire at UTC + 2 and your host's time is UTC + 2, then you have set your token to expire immediately.

The EXP claim in a toke in a UTC time stamp, which is a long expressing the number of seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. You can get this value on windows like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current UTC Timestamp is {DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()}");
    }
```

Which results in

> Current UTC Timestamp is 1614087653

Get the time on the host and verify that the EXP claim in the token > the current UTC Timestamp on the host. For good measure, log the message above on your container.

Comment: On host is expired, I don't have a problem with that, on docker should not based on the timestamp, but when validated at authorization in docker it says it is not authorized.

Comment: My problem is at docker authorization, saying it is expired when it should not be on docker.

Comment: Updated the highlighted section of the question, that was misleading. So in couple of words, token issued on container with salability of 2 hours is valid for 1 minute when validated on container, if I change HOST time with -1 hour, token is valid on container for another hour. The symptoms, token is issued using utc time from container, but when validate on same container it was issued utc date time on host is used as reference. And it fails. That's it.